# Is there a powershell command that would power on another host?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have a group of computers that I want to power off and then power back on, is there a Powershell command that will do this? I have the 'shutdown' command to turn them off, I can't use the reboot command.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use powershell 5.0 + , you can use the **Restart-Computer** cmdlet.

```bsh
$computers = @('name1','name2')

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer -Force
}
```

Another alternative is  using the **shutdown** with **CMD**.

```
shutdown -i
```

Will pop up a nice GUI to do your requirements.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use WMI in your PowerShell script, the `Win32_OperatingSystem` WMI class object has methods called [`Win32Shutdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32shutdown-method-in-class-win32-operatingsystem) and [`Win32ShutdownTracker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32shutdowntracker-method-in-class-win32-operatingsystem), either of which will allow you to shutdown or reboot a computer, or forcibly log off a remote user. I’ve created a scriptlet/script cmdlet/advanced function that uses the latter to do exactly what you’re looking to do; it works with any version of Windows PowerShell from 2.0 on:

```
function Close-UserSession {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Logs off a remote user, or reboots a remote computer.
.DESCRIPTION
Logs off a remote user, or reboots a remote computer.
Optionally, forces the logoff or reboot without waiting for running programs to terminate.
.INPUTS
This cmdlet can accept a computer object from the pipeline.
Default is to act on the local computer.
.OUTPUTS
Returns the success or failure of the attempt to logoff/reboot the remote computer.
.PARAMETER ComputerName
The name of the computer to log off or reboot.
.PARAMETER Reboot
If present, causes the computer to reboot instead of logging off the current user.
.PARAMETER Force
If present, forces the logoff/reboot without waiting for running programs to shut down.
.Parameter Delay
Defaults to 0. Specifies the number of seconds to wait before logging off or rebooting
.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> Close-UserSession -ComputerName WPBBX-LW57359
(Would cause the current user on the indicated computer to be logged off immediately)
.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> Close-UserSession -Reboot -ComputerName WPBBX-LW57359 -Delay 30
(Would cause the indicated computer to reboot after 30 seconds)
.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> Close-UserSession -ComputerName WPBBX-LW57359 -Reboot -Force
(Forces an immediate reboot of the indicated computer without waiting for programs to shut down.)
#>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]

    param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

    [Switch]$Force,

    [Alias("Boot","Restart")]
    [Switch]$Reboot,

    [int]$Delay = 0
    )
    $logoff   =  0
    $shutdown =  1
    $rebootit =  2
    $forceit  =  4
    $poweroff =  8

    $func = 0 #default is to just log the user off
    $message = "Logging you off for ITSD troubleshooting "
    if ($Reboot) {
        $func = $func -bor $rebootit #reboot the indicated computer
        $message = "Rebooting the computer for ITSD troubleshooting "
        }
    if ($Force)  { $func = $func -bor $forceit  } #Force the logoff or reboot without worrying about closing files
    if ($Delay -eq 0) {
        $message = $message + "now!"
    } else {
        $message = $message + "in $Delay seconds."
    }
    $RemoteOS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    if ($psCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ComputerName)) {
        ($RemoteOS.Win32ShutdownTracker($Delay,$message,0,$func)).ReturnValue
    }
}
```